# Capturing group for sentences with alternatives

Tags: regex

I want to capture these two French sentences.

1. Je ne pense pas que
2. Pensez-vous que

Please correct my RE.

```
(je )? (ne )?(?: pense|pensez)(?: -)?(vous )?(?: pas)? que
```

Comment: This question shows no effort.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple?

```
/(Je ne pense pas|Pensez-vous) que/
```

Or even simpler

```
/(Je ne pense pas que|Pensez-vous que)/
```